# Revit API WPF C#: Check All button for Check Boxes in Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, revit-api

I'm pretty new to programming with WPF and C# and I have a question regarding the possibility to automatically check all the CheckBoxes in a Listbox. I'm developing a plugin for Autodesk Revit and, after having listed all the names of the rooms in a list box, I want to check them all using the button "Check All"

I've read the thread [at this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751635/how-can-i-check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-in-listbox-in-c-sharp-wpf) but still, I'm not able to make it work. May someone help me with my code?

Here is what I've done:

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name='roomlist'
              SelectionMode='Multiple'>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <CheckBox IsChecked='{Binding IsChecked}'
                        Content="{Binding}" />
           </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.InputBindings>
           <KeyBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.SelectAll"
                       Modifiers="Ctrl"
                       Key="A" />
        </ListBox.InputBindings>
        <ListBox.CommandBindings>
           <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.SelectAll" />
        </ListBox.CommandBindings>
     </ListBox>
```

C#

```
public partial class RoomsDistance_Form : Window
{
    UIDocument _uidoc;
    Document _doc;

    public RoomsDistance_Form(Document doc, UIDocument uidoc) 
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
            .WhereElementIsNotElementType()
            .OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Rooms);

        List<String> myRooms = new List<String>();
        foreach (var c in collector)
        {
            myRooms.Add(c.Name);
        }
        myRooms.Sort();
        roomlist.ItemsSource = myRooms;
    }


    private void checkAllBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        foreach (CheckBox item in roomlist.Items.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            item.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }

    public class Authority : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return isChecked; }
            set
            {
                isChecked = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having lost my mind in the effort i solved my problem by avoiding the Listbox.. I simply added single CheckBoxes in the StackPanel.

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin='10,45,10,100'
                BorderThickness='1'>
     <StackPanel x:Name='stack'
                 Grid.Column='0'></StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
```

C#:

```
foreach (var x in myRooms)
        {
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            chk.Content = x;
            stack.Children.Add(chk);
        }
```

Not what i was looking for but now it works and that's the point.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the thread you are linking to, they are setting the "IsChecked" on the data object (Authority), not the CheckBox control itself.

```
foreach (var a in authorityList)
{
     a.IsChecked = true;
}
```

You have a binding to `IsChecked` that will update the `Checkbox` control when `NotifyPropertyChanged()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use CheckBoxList in the following way:

In xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> //+some dimensional properties
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel ViewModel {get; set; }

    public MyWindow(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        //keep all the mess in ViewModel, this way your xaml.cs will not end up with 1k lines
        ViewModel = viewModel;
        DataContext = ViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void BtnClick_SelectAll(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.CheckAll();
    }
}
```

ViewModel preparation:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<ListBoxItem> ListBoxItems { get; set; }

    //InitializeViewModel()...
    //UpdateViewModel()...
    //other things....
    
    public void CheckAll()
    {
        foreach (var item in ListBoxItems) 
        {
            item.IsSelected = true;
        }    
    }

public class ListBoxItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected != value)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```